# Нестандартный парсинг JSON в Spring Boot

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Есть такой объект:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@ALLArgsConstructor
public class MyClass{
    @Data
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @ALLArgsConstructor
    private class InnerClass{
        private String field1;
        private String field2;
    }
    private InnerClass innerField;
}
```

Есть такой JSON:

```
{
    "myclass.innerfield.field1":"value1",
    "myclass.innerfield.field2":"value2"
}
```

Нужно получить этот объект из этого JSON в контроллере.

Пробовал так. Метод контроллера:

```
public void myMethod(@RequestBody MyClass request){
}
```

Не работает.
Добавлял JsonProperty

```
@JsonProperty("myclass.innerfield.field1")
private String field1;
```

Не помогает.

**Вопрос: Как из этого JSON получить тот объект, что описан мной в самом начале?**

JSON приходит из внешнего сервиса. Поэтому "подогнать его под себя" не получится.

Comment: а там точно запятая в конце есть в этой строке "myclass.innerfield.field2":"value2", ? просто это синтаксическая ошибка для json. в этом случае надо обрабатывать сырой запрос, потому как на json с ошибкой любой сериализатор загнется

Comment: @Дмитрий, запятой нет. Просто была моя опечатка, когда набирал текст вопроса..

Comment: тогда что в нем нестандартного? обычный json и на вид все верно. заочно довольно сложно сказать... а этот сервер в открытом доступе? можете ссылку дать? пробовали ли десериализовать в Map?

Comment: @Дмитрий, к сожалению, этот сервер доступен только для служебного пользования. За совет относительно Map спасибо! Позже попробую.

Comment: @Дмитрий, спасибо! Помогло!

Comment: да не за что. дедовский метод)))